# Using glColor* with OpenGL version 4.4

Tags: windows, opengl, glew, openglcontext

I am in the process of updating our ancient OpenGL code. It is a Windows system and I am using GLEW. The OpenGL version is 4.4 (previously, the way the context was created limited us to 1.1). The code base is large and so I want to update it in stages (i.e. get everything working now on a version higher than 1.1 with minimal work). So far, I found only one break. Transparency no longer works. I suspect this may be due to glColor* or glTexEnv* being deprecated. I tried to request a specific version of OpenGL but was not successful. Can you tell me what I am doing wrong in context creation or what changes I can make to the draw code to get transparency to work? (Other help appreciated of course.)

Here is the context creation code (error checking removed for readability):

```
PIXELFORMATDESCRIPTOR pfd = {
    /*WORD  nSize*/           sizeof(PIXELFORMATDESCRIPTOR),
    /*WORD  nVersion*/        1,
    /*DWORD dwFlags*/         PFD_DRAW_TO_WINDOW | PFD_SUPPORT_OPENGL,
    /*BYTE  iPixelType*/      PFD_TYPE_RGBA,
    /*BYTE  cColorBits*/      24,
    /*BYTE  cRedBits*/        0,
    /*BYTE  cRedShift*/       0,
    /*BYTE  cGreenBits*/      0,
    /*BYTE  cGreenShift*/     0,
    /*BYTE  cBlueBits*/       0,
    /*BYTE  cBlueShift*/      0,
    /*BYTE  cAlphaBits*/      8,
    /*BYTE  cAlphaShift*/     0,
    /*BYTE  cAccumBits*/      0,
    /*BYTE  cAccumRedBits*/   0,
    /*BYTE  cAccumGreenBits*/ 0,
    /*BYTE  cAccumBlueBits*/  0,
    /*BYTE  cAccumAlphaBits*/ 0,
    /*BYTE  cDepthBits*/      16,
    /*BYTE  cStencilBits*/    0,
    /*BYTE  cAuxBuffers*/     0,
    /*BYTE  iLayerType*/      PFD_MAIN_PLANE,
    /*BYTE  bReserved*/       0,
    /*DWORD dwLayerMask*/     0,
    /*DWORD dwVisibleMask*/   0,
    /*DWORD dwDamageMask*/    0
};
int nPixelFormat = ChoosePixelFormat(hDC, &pfd);
SetPixelFormat(hDC, nPixelFormat, &pfd);

hRC_ = wglCreateContext(hDC);
wglMakeCurrent(hDC, hRC_);

MsgUtil::TraceWin("version: %s", glGetString(GL_VERSION)); // Output: version: 4.4.0

glewInit();

GLint attribs[] = {
    WGL_CONTEXT_MAJOR_VERSION_ARB, 3,
    WGL_CONTEXT_MINOR_VERSION_ARB, 0,
    WGL_CONTEXT_PROFILE_MASK_ARB, WGL_CONTEXT_COMPATIBILITY_PROFILE_BIT_ARB,
    0
};

HGLRC CompHRC = wglCreateContextAttribsARB(hDC, 0, attribs);
if (CompHRC && wglMakeCurrent(hDC, CompHRC)){
hRC_ = CompHRC;
}

MsgUtil::TraceWin("version: %s", glGetString(GL_VERSION)); // Output: version: 4.4.0
```

Even after requesting version 3.0, `glGetString(GL_VERSION)` returns 4.4.0. I draw to a framebuffer and then use `glReadPixels()` to write to a bitmap (though I don't think that is especially relevant here).

Here is the framebuffer code (stays bound for lifetime of context):

```
glGenFramebuffers(1, &defaultFramebuffer);
glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, defaultFramebuffer);

glGenRenderbuffers(1, &colorRenderbuffer);
glBindRenderbuffer(GL_RENDERBUFFER, colorRenderbuffer);
glRenderbufferStorage(GL_RENDERBUFFER, GL_RGBA, framebufferWidth, framebufferHeight);

glFramebufferRenderbuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, GL_RENDERBUFFER, colorRenderbuffer);

glGenRenderbuffers(1, &depthRenderbuffer);
glBindRenderbuffer(GL_RENDERBUFFER, depthRenderbuffer);
glRenderbufferStorage(GL_RENDERBUFFER, GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT16, framebufferWidth, framebufferHeight);
glFramebufferRenderbuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_DEPTH_ATTACHMENT, GL_RENDERBUFFER, depthRenderbuffer);
```

Here is the draw code:

```
glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
glTexEnvf(GL_TEXTURE_ENV, GL_TEXTURE_ENV_MODE, GL_MODULATE);
glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
glColor4f(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, alpha);

glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture_id);

glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D,GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP);
glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D,GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP);
glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D,GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D,GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);

glPixelStorei(GL_UNPACK_ALIGNMENT, 1);  
glPixelStorei(GL_UNPACK_ROW_LENGTH, 0);
glPixelStorei(GL_UNPACK_SKIP_ROWS, 0);
glPixelStorei(GL_UNPACK_SKIP_PIXELS, 0);

// Turn theImage (a CImage) into a texture
HBITMAP hbitmap = NewCreateDib24(*window_dc_, MAX_DELTA, MAX_DELTA);
CBitmap* bitmap = CBitmap::FromHandle(hbitmap);
CDC* memDC = new CDC();
memDC->CreateCompatibleDC(window_dc_);
CBitmap* pOldBitmap = memDC->SelectObject(bitmap);
theImage.StretchBlt(*memDC, 0, 0, MAX_DELTA, MAX_DELTA, SRCCOPY);
LPBYTE tempbitsMem = new BYTE[bm_info.bmiHeader.biSizeImage];
bitmap->GetBitmapBits(bm_info.bmiHeader.biSizeImage, (LPVOID)tempbitsMem);

glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, 3, MAX_DELTA, MAX_DELTA, 0, GL_BGR, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, tempbitsMem);

// Draw texture     
glBegin(GL_QUADS);
glTexCoord2d(tx.x_, 1.0 - tx.y_);
glVertex2d(px.x_, px.y_);
glTexCoord2d(t0.x_, 1.0 - t0.y_);
glVertex2d(p0.x_, p0.y_ );
glTexCoord2d(ty.x_, 1.0 - ty.y_);
glVertex2d(py.x_, py.y_);
glTexCoord2d(txy.x_, 1.0 - txy.y_);
glVertex2d(pxy.x_, pxy.y_); 
glEnd();
```

The texture is now applied with full opacity, regardless of the alpha value sent to `glColor4f()`. However, if I change the RGB values, then that is still reflected in the output.

Comment: Lots of things you are trying to do are not available in a core profile. `GL_CLAMP` as a texture repeat mode first of all as well as immediate mode and "current color". Transparency not working is very subjective, however. The only form of transparency I see you are using here is alpha blending, and that depends on draw order. There are other things that "transparency no longer works" could mean, for instance, if your framebuffer was supposed to store a destination alpha channel (it currently does not, you have allocated 32-bits for RGB and 0-bits for alpha - a format better known as RGBx).

Comment: The draw order is correct. I am confused about your statement `(it currently does not, you have allocated 32-bits for RGB and 0-bits for alpha - a format better known as RGBx)` since I didn't provide the details of the framebuffer creation. Are you referring to the texture creation?

Comment: You did provide the details of framebuffer creation. In your PixelFormat Descriptor. `PFD_TYPE_RGBA, 32, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, ...` tells WGL that you want a format with 32-bit color and 0-bit alpha. It will generally give you 8-bits for Red, Green and Blue and add an extra 8-bits for alignment. Now, destination alpha (the alpha component stored in your framebuffer) is insignificant for alpha blending given your blend function. But if you were trying to use the framebuffer for alpha compositing, then you would definitely need to store destination alpha for transparency to work.

Comment: Ah, ok. I set pfd.cColorBits = 24 and pfd.cAlphaBits = 8. Now `DescribePixelFormat()` shows that I am getting 8 bits for each of RGBA (previously I was missing alpha). However, still no transparency.

Comment: I edited the post to reflect the change in context creation code and added code for framebuffer creation. I am unsure how these two interact, but I requested a framebuffer with an alpha channel and it was complete, so ...

Answer (score 2):

You should ask for a compatibility profile instead of a core profile.

Comment: That makes sense. I changed `WGL_CONTEXT_CORE_PROFILE_BIT_ARB` to `WGL_CONTEXT_COMPATIBILITY_PROFILE_BIT_ARB`. However, I get the same result.

Comment: Although what was suggested here helped me out, I'm still dealing with the same issue. If interested I posted the reformed question here: (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21921353/glblendfunc-and-framebuffer-object)